# Free cyclic subgroups in a non-abelian group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there any non-abelian group $G$ such that for each $a\in G$ and any automorphism $g:\left<a\right>\to \left<a\right>$ the function
$$f:G\to G$$
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{ if } x\in \left<a\right> \\ 
x & \text{ if } x\notin \left<a\right>
\end{cases}$$
is an automorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Pick $a\in G$ for which $\langle a\rangle$ has a nontrivial automorphism $g$.

Let $b\not\in\langle a\rangle$. What's $f(ab)$? What's $f(a)f(b)$? Can these be equal?

The issue here is that complements of a subset closed under an operation need not themselves be closed, for instance irrational + irrational can be rational, so defining a homomorphism piecewise in this manner is almost surely doomed to fail.

Comment: My question is if **certainly** fails in non-abelian case?

Comment: @user138171 Have you **tried** using what I've told you to answer that? It should be easy to answer using what I've outlined. What kinds of cyclic groups have no nontrivial automorphism? Can a nonabelian group have no cyclic subgroup with a nontrivial automorphism? In a nonabelian subgroup, does every cyclic subgroup have nonempty complement? Answer all these things, then figure out how to put the information together. Do some thinking!